# Calculating the 'deviance' in an Analysis of Deviance table for generalized linear models

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, deviance

The issue concerns question 3(b) of [this paper.](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/sites/www.maths.cam.ac.uk/files/pre2014/postgrad/mathiii/pastpapers/2012/PaperIII_37.pdf)

Specifically, I am trying to fill in the missing values for the 'Deviance' column of the ANOVA table. Using R, I find the missing corresponding to 'Day' to be 0.2733. However, when I try to verify this by direct calculation with
$$2[\ell_{\mathrm{proposed}}-\ell_{\mathrm{null}}]=2\left[\sum_{i,j,k}n_{ijk}Y_{ijk}\alpha_{i}+n_{ijk}\log\left(\frac{1+\exp(\mu)}{1+\exp(\mu+\alpha_i)}\right)\right]$$
Note that here I've assumed the model $n_{ijk}Y_{ijk}\sim B(n_{ijk},p_{ijk})$ where $\mathrm{logit} p_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i$ for day $i=1,2,3$, species $j = 1,2,3$ and observation $k = 1,\ldots, K_{ij}$. I cannot seem to obtain the correct answer when observations from the table are plugged into the above (also, here $n_{ijk}$ denotes values from the  'total' columns). Could someone please give a model solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is considered an acceptable answer or not, but the lazy way to solve this exam question is to note this line in the `summary()` output:

```
Null deviance: 33.631 on 22 degrees of freedom
```

and these lines in the deviance table:

```
      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev P(>|Chi|)
NULL
Day   xx xx       20        33.358     0.8723
```

Since the null deviance is 33.631 and the residual deviance (`Resid Dev`) is 33.358, the *difference* in deviance between the null model and the model with `Day`  only (which is what's listed in the `Deviance` column) is 33.631-33.358 = 0.273.

You can get the difference in degrees of freedom (`Df`) similarly (null [22] - residual [20] = 2), or by explaining that `Day` is a categorical predictor with 3 levels and thus requires 3-1 = 2 additional parameters over the null (intercept-only) model.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling I was overthinking it. I'd worked out everything else in a similar fashion to this and completely overlooked the null deviance!